# Java unchecked cast from base class to sub class using generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have the following:

```
class Main {
    static class TypeA<A> {}
    static class TypeB<A, B> extends TypeA<A> {}

    static <X> void aMethod(TypeA<X> a) {
        if (a instanceof TypeB) {
            TypeB<X, ?> b = (TypeB<X, ?>) a;
            // Do stuff with b
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aMethod(new TypeB<Integer, Object>());
    }
}
```

I get an unchecked cast warning casting from `TypeA<X>` to `TypeB<X, ?>`.  The type named `X` is the same according to `TypeB`'s definition, so I don't see why this fails.  I can lose the type info by casting `TypeB<?, ?> b = (TypeB<?, ?>) a;`, but I need to keep `X`.

Why am I unable to safely cast from a base class with a generic parameter to a sub-class with the same generic parameter?

Comment: I actually don't get this warning if I put this exact code in to an IDE. MCVE would be helpful, I guess. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It warns on Eclipse.

Comment: Edited to a MCVE.  I get the warning in eclipse.  I do not get the warning when using `javac` directly.  I'm using java version `1.8.0_77`.

Comment: You could just add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to that call, if you wish to simply ignore it. Not a solution, but I have encountered some cases where it's impossible to rectify the code to prevent that warning from occurring and I've had to use the suppression attribute instead.

Comment: I think this is an Eclipse bug. (Or let's say a "non-JLS compliant behavior".) Does the warning give any extra info about what Eclipse thinks is going on? If you compile with `-Xint unchecked` it might give you a more descriptive message as well.

Comment: If I'm absolutely certain that it's safe, that will be fine, but I'm working on a particularly complex generics problem and want as few warnings suppressed as possible and a good reason _why_ I'm suppressing.  For this particular case, I don't know why the compiler is having trouble.

Comment: `javac -Xint unchecked Main.java` produces no output, and eclipse only says "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Main.TypeA<X> to Main.TypeB<X,?>".  Since `javac` doesn't report an issue, I feel more comfortable suppressing the warning.

Comment: Your intuition about the safety of the cast is correct so you could suppress it. It's just icky that Eclipse is doing this I guess.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 15 doesn't complain at all.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like eclipse is dropping the ball.  I feel comfortable suppressing the warning with a message that it's eclipse's problem, not my code.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: No warning in Intellij 2016 either - I really think this is an Eclipse bug. How are you compiling, Maven?